# Record Id and Type coming as null when I get the result from a saved search in a suitscript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a saved search already in my sandbox account.I am not sure on what record the saved search is created. I tried loading the saved search as :

```
var savedSearch = nlapiLoadSearch("item", searchId);
var resultset = savedSearch.runSearch();
resultset.getResults(0, 1000);//Actually I have looped and got all my search results.
```

When I run it on the debugger I get to see the results in the columns correctly, but I see the recordId and recordType of the savedsearch result is null. I want to have the recordtype, so that I can load that particular record as required.

Attached is a screenshot of the debugger results in variables section.[image: Debugger Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the methods Eric mentions are returning nulls the your search is probably using aggregates like count and sum.

You can get internal id by including internal id as a group field and you can include type as a group field too but you can't use it directly like you can results[i].getRecordType()

Comment: Exactly @bknights, I had included type as a group field too and solved the issue. My saved search is using aggregates I see. I had also expected the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

`nlobjSearchResult` Objects have `getId()` and `getRecordType()` methods for this purpose.

For example, if you store your results in an Array called `searchResults`:

```js
searchResults.forEach(printResult);

function printResult(result) {
    var recordId = result.getId();
    var recordType = result.getRecordType();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already tried these, I am getting null for the said variables, and from my screenshot also its shown those values are null.

Comment: Would help to show your search Criteria and Results